# Using a different PHP version to compile Magento project

Tags: magento2, developer-mode, compilation

I have a site running Magento-CE-2.1.5 in a ubuntu server.

I have 2 PHP versions running alongside:

1. PHP 7.0.18
2. PHP 7.1.6.

Each time i try to setup Magento it shows PHP version 7.0.18 but the real problem is that I need to make few changes and compile the projects.

At the time of compiling, the Magento PHP command uses PHP version 7.1.6. How can i make the project use PHP version 7.0.18 during compilation?

I have PHP 7.1.6 version as it was required by a Laravel site running PHP 7.1.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending upon how you installed the different PHP versions (e.g. using ondrej's PPA to install 5.6/7.0/7.1 or compiling from source) you should have two separate "php" executables under `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.  I use the PPA and it provides the following executables for me:

- `/usr/bin/php5.6`
- `/usr/bin/php7.0`
- `/usr/bin/php7.1`

To run the `bin/magento` command using a specific version of PHP, just call that specific version of the executable followed by `bin/magento <command>`.  For example:

`php5.6 bin/magento setup:di:compile`
`php7.0 bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Also if you're using the PPA and providing multiple versions of one package, you could look to see if `/usr/bin/php` links to `/etc/alternatives/php`.  If so, then you can do `sudo update-alternatives --config php` and select which one `/usr/bin/php` will use, thus allowing you to just use `php` to be running whichever you choose (on the command-line).

Comment: perfect answer with explanation! +1 made my day!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the path variable to match to version of php that you want to run.

```
php -v 
set PATH="/usr/bin/php7.0:$PATH"
php -v
```

Note that I assume you php7.0 is under `/usr/bin/php7.0` but that can easily be changed base on where your system stores it's files.

Also on some systems you will be able to find `php`, `php7.0` and `php7.1` commands on the CLI

Comment: Thaks its work fine for me!!