# Running composer with php7.0

Tags: magento-2.1, composer, php-7

I have a server where I have two versions of PHP installed (PHP-7.0 and PHP-7.1). I also have two sites one using magento2.1.5 (running PHP-7.0.18) and the other a Code Ignitor project(running PHP-7.1.6).
We all know magento2.1.5 is not compatible with PHP-7.1.6. I am compiling Magento projects using [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179887/using-a-different-php-version-to-compile-magento-project) and it works fine.
Now I need to use Composer, each time i run `composer install` it shows the following error:

```
Problem 1
- magento/composer 1.0.3 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/composer 1.0.3 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Installation request for magento/composer 1.0.3 -> satisfiable by magento/composer[1.0.3].
```

Any solution would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell composer to ignore the platform requirements by adding the `--ignore-platform-reqs` parameter in `composer install`, `composer update` etc.

Or you can specify the used production version in your projects `composer.json` with the "platform" parameter:

```
"config": {
  "platform": {
    "php": "7.0.18"
  }
}
```

This way you also ensure that `composer update` only installs packages that are compatible with PHP 7.0

Comment: does this create any side-effects later

Comment: @Wildfire it's possible that composer installs packages that require php 7.1 when running composer update with that parameter. To avoid this, use `platform` (see updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check in composer.json for below line

```
"require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0"
```

Change the above line  to

```
"require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0|~7.1.0"
```

Then run the composer install.

I hope it will works... Try it..

Comment: theres no such line in my composer.json